# Recent Apps on UiAutomator

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I am now working with Android UiAutomator on for UI Test on my Android app. My app has a function that requires the user to verify the email to continue, so I try to do it like this: after reach to that function -> getUiDevice.pressHome -> Browser -> try to log in email -> PressHome again -> Press RecentApps then I stuck here, I cannot press on my Apps to return to it again. I try another way by clicking on my App icon but it starts my app again, not at the state before. Can anyone suggest me a solution for this? Any help is appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Try this :

```
UiObject appBackground = new UiObject(new UiSelector().description("ABC"));
appBackground.click();
```

It did not show any description through 'uiautomatorviewer' command but this worked for me.

Comment: hi Smriti,
I haven't done this anymore (at least at the moment) but if i got stuck into this case again in the future I will try your method. Thanks for showing me :)

Comment: @DucTran please accept this answer. It works perfectly on an emulator w/ Marshmallow and Nexus 6P w/ Nougat. I think this is the correct answer.

Comment: new UiOject(UiSelector) is deprecated - use UiDevice.findObject(UiSelector) instead.

Comment: This method will also not work on Android 9 and above where the Recent Apps also have shortcuts to common apps. This method will find the shortcut instead, click it, and effectively launch the app as it would if you were to hit the app icon.

Answer (score 3):

I could manage to create this behavior with:

```
fun backgroundAndForeground() {
    val device = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation())
    device.pressHome()
    // Pressing app switch two times makes the last app put on background come to foreground.
    device.pressKeyCode(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH)
    device.pressKeyCode(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think that android only resume app when clicking the recent app image. It does not work on clicking display text or app icon. So, we need to click image of your app in recent app list. At that time you need to write as below. I always do that for similar case.

```
// Take all image view by class type and click by instance no.
new UiObject(new UiSelector().className("android.widget.ImageView").instance(3)).click();
```

You need to count instance no of your recent app image view. Not app icon image in recent app scroll view. Please try this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent half a day on this and concluded I needed to issue a `device.click()`. Since my use-case is that my app was the last one running (not switching to the browser like you), I can safely click the middle of the screen and it'll always work.

If you're the 2nd to last running app, you can probably do x: `0` and y: `device.displayHeight/2`.

I've not tested this on many operating systems, only 9.